# how to do Auth Authentication in lumen api?

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

I have checked using `Auth::attempt(['email' => $request->email_id, 'password' => $request->password])` which works in web side but gives false in api side .

```
if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $request->email_id, 'password' => $request->password])) 
            dd("Successfully Authenticated ");
                 else dd("false");
```

Comment: Please learn to apply [PSR1](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-1/) and [PSR2](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/) in your code

Answer (score 0):

Use JWT authentication to authenticate your lumen api

```
composer require tymon/jwt-auth
```

after installation follow the configuration

https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth/wiki

Below authenticate function help to authenticate and return the API token

```
use JWTAuth;
use Tymon\JWTAuth\Exceptions\JWTException;

class AuthenticateController extends Controller
{
    public function authenticate(Request $request)
    {
        // grab credentials from the request
        $credentials = $request->only('email', 'password');

        try {
            // attempt to verify the credentials and create a token for the user
            if (! $token = JWTAuth::attempt($credentials)) {
                return response()->json(['error' => 'invalid_credentials'], 401);
            }
        } catch (JWTException $e) {
            // something went wrong whilst attempting to encode the token
            return response()->json(['error' => 'could_not_create_token'], 500);
        }

        // all good so return the token
        return response()->json(compact('token'));
    }
}
```